# Change Session State Provider dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are currently using cookieless session via the Web.Config

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

When you first hit a web page will do a redirect to itself and mangles the URL to include the session id.

My first question is: For certain page is possible to avoid this? I am trying to change the Session State Provider if the page name = XXXXX. I need it to just show the page without the redirect.

The Second Question is: Is there a way to switch Session providers from Custom to SQL in the Global.asax. In Some cases we need to use SQL others we need Custom.

I have tried Changing the `SessionStateMode` to `SQL` in the Global.asax in the Session_Start but no luck. Any ideas?

Edit

As for my first question I have found a Page Directive that will do the trick

```
EnableSessionState="false"
```

I still need to figure out how to switch providers in the Global.asax

To Expand We, are currently using cookieless session but we are switching to a Custom Provider(State Server). We need an auto failover to SQL should that server not be available.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your answer is here

in global.asax put

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    Configuration config;
    config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    SessionStateSection SessionState = config.GetSection("system.web/sessionState") as SessionStateSection;

    if (SessionState != null)
    {
    SessionState.Mode = System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateMode.InProc;
    //SessionState.Mode = (SessionStateSection)"Mode=InProc";
    //(SessionStateSection)"Inproc";
    config.Save();
    }
}
```

http://www.totaltechnet.com/UpdateConfig/UpdateConfig.htm

Edit: my bad. it looks like this actually writes the new value the web.config

Comment: Yes it does, but still this should be usable, provided that you check in code if web.config needs to be changed or not. Without such a check, the application would keep on recycling because it restarts each time web.config is changed.

Answer (score 2):

The global event `Session_Start` happens after the session is initialized.  If you need to make changes before that, you'd have to hook an earlier event, like [`AcquireRequestState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate.aspx).

Here's [a talk from Tech Days Hyderabad](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/12/19/my-session-summary-microsoft-community-tech-days-18-dec-2010-hyderabad/) about customizing session state using a HTTP module.  It suggests [`SetSessionStateBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.setsessionstatebehavior.aspx) but that only allows you to enable/disable session state, not to switch provider.

Looks like you could modify your custom provider to read SQL State.  Here's a post on how to [manually decode session state](http://forums.asp.net/t/978762.aspx/1).  That probably won't survive a change in .NET versions though,